# Update Value Object fileld in Mvc code First

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I have a value object named Validity and its attribute StartDate and EndDate.
I have Update this field.but getting some error.The error is:

InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Validity' has a defining navigation and the supplied entity is currently not being tracked. To start tracking this entity call '.Reference().TargetEntry' on the owner entry.

How to solve this error?

My Code Is:

```cs
public async Task<Subscription> Update(string ID, bool Active, string Plan, string Periodicity, decimal Price, string LocationTargets, string paymentStatus,
            DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string OperationType)
        {
            #region PaymentStatus
            int EnumPaymentStatus = 0;
            string[] values = Enum.GetNames(typeof(PaymentStatusEnum.PaymentStatus));

            if (values[0] == paymentStatus)
            {
                EnumPaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatus.Due;
            }
            else if (values[1] == paymentStatus)
            {
                EnumPaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatus.Open;
            }
            else if (values[2] == paymentStatus)
            {
                EnumPaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatus.UnPaid;
            }
            else if (values[3] == paymentStatus)
            {
                EnumPaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatus.Paid;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Periodicity
            int EnumPeriodicityValue = 0;
            string[] values1 = Enum.GetNames(typeof(PeriodicityEnum.EnumPeriodicity));

            if (values1[0] == Periodicity)
            {
                EnumPeriodicityValue = (int)EnumPeriodicity.Monthly;
            }
            else if (values1[1] == Periodicity)
            {
                EnumPeriodicityValue = (int)EnumPeriodicity.Trimestral;
            }
            else if (values1[2] == Periodicity)
            {
                EnumPeriodicityValue = (int)EnumPeriodicity.Semestral;
            }
            else if (values1[3] == Periodicity)
            {
                EnumPeriodicityValue = (int)EnumPeriodicity.Annual;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Operation Type
            int OperationTypeValue = 0;
            string[] values2 = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OperationTypeEnum.EnumOperationType));

            if (values2[0] == OperationType)
            {
                OperationTypeValue = (int)EnumOperationType.NewSubscription;
            }
            else if (values2[1] == OperationType)
            {
                OperationTypeValue = (int)EnumOperationType.SubscriptionRenewal;
            }
            else if (values2[2] == OperationType)
            {
                OperationTypeValue = (int)EnumOperationType.SubscriptionCancellation;
            }
            else if (values2[3] == OperationType)
            {
                OperationTypeValue = (int)EnumOperationType.SubscriptionChange;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Update Data in Subscription Table
            var subscription = new Subscription()
            {
                ID = ID,
                Active = Active,
                Plan = Plan,
                Periodicity = Convert.ToString(EnumPeriodicityValue),
                Price = Price,
                LocationTargets = LocationTargets,
                PaymentStatus = Convert.ToString(EnumPaymentStatus),
                OperationType = Convert.ToString(OperationTypeValue),
                UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            subscription.Validity = new Validity(startDate, endDate);
            //Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<Subscription> s = await _db.AddAsync(subscription);



            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.Active).IsModified = true;
            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.Plan).IsModified = true;
            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.Periodicity).IsModified = true;
            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.Price).IsModified = true;
            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.LocationTargets).IsModified = true;
            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.PaymentStatus).IsModified = true;

            _db.Entry(subscription.Validity).Property(x => x.StartDate).IsModified = true;
            _db.Entry(subscription.Validity).Property(x => x.EndDate).IsModified = true;



            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.OperationType).IsModified = true;
            _db.Entry(subscription).Property(x => x.UpdatedAt).IsModified = true;

            #endregion

            #region Insert Data in SubscriptionHistory Table

            string a = Convert.ToString(GuidComb.Generate());
            var subscriptionhistory = new SubscriptionHistory()
            {
                ID = a,
                Active = Active,
                Plan = Plan,
                Periodicity = Convert.ToString(EnumPeriodicityValue),
                Price = Price,
                LocationTargets = LocationTargets,
                PaymentStatus = Convert.ToString(EnumPaymentStatus),
                OperationType = Convert.ToString(OperationTypeValue)
            };
            subscriptionhistory.Validity = new Validity(startDate, endDate);

            Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<SubscriptionHistory> y = await _db.AddAsync(subscriptionhistory);

            #endregion

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return subscription;
        }


In Subscription Class:
 public class Subscription: BaseEntity
    {
        public Subscription()
        {
            this.ID = Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid());
            this.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            this.IsCancel = false;
        }

        private List<Validity> validities = new List<Validity>();

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Plan { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(101)]
        public string Periodicity { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string LocationTargets { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(101)]
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }

        public Validity Validity { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(101)]
        public string OperationType { get; set; }

        public bool IsCancel { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime DeletedAt { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        //private List<Validity> validities = new List<Validity>();

        public void Assignvalidity(Validity validitys)
        {
            this.validities.Add(validitys);
        }

    }

In Validity Class:

 public class Validity : ValueObject
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }

        private Validity() { }

        public Validity(DateTime  startdate, DateTime enddate)
        {
            StartDate = startdate;
            EndDate = enddate;
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
        {
            yield return StartDate;
            yield return EndDate;
        }

    }
```

Comment: just post your codes of how you do get the entity and how you update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry s =  _db.Update(subscription);

After this line:
subscription.Validity = new Validity(startDate, endDate);

Answer (score 0):

In order to update an entity it must be tracked by the entity, in your below code you are creating new object :

```cs
var subscription = new Subscription()
            {
                ID = ID,
                Active = Active,
                Plan = Plan,
                Periodicity = Convert.ToString(EnumPeriodicityValue),
                Price = Price,
                LocationTargets = LocationTargets,
                PaymentStatus = Convert.ToString(EnumPaymentStatus),
                OperationType = Convert.ToString(OperationTypeValue),
                UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
```

First you need to get that entity from the db, then update related fields and save to db;

[UPDATE]

The validity is a related entity to Subscription, so you need an include query to fetch the object from the db, then you can update and save.

```cs
var subscription = _db.Set<Subscription>().Single(x=>x.ID == ID).Include(x=>x.Validity);

subscription.Validity.StartDate = startDate;
subscription.Vaklidity.EndDate = endDate;

_db.SaveChanges();
```

[UPDATE]

add foreignkey attributes then create a new migration then update the db:

```cs
public class Validity : ValueObject
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public string SubscriptionID { get; set; }
        public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }

        // ...
    }

public class Subscription: BaseEntity
    {
        public string ValidityID { get; set; }
        public Validity Validity { get; set; }

        // ...
    }
```

After updating the db, get the related Validity entity and update it:

```cs
var validity = _db.Set<Validity>().Find(x => x.SubscriptionID == ID);

validity.StartDate = startDate;
validity.EndDate = endDate;

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: can you show your full class members of Subscription and Validity? as far as I see you have a different object for validity, right?

Comment: Ok,I am updating in posted questions

Comment: Already Posted subscription class and validity class(value object)

Comment: I use this query but some error occured:
CS1061 C# Subscription does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well, most probably you don’t have Validity table in your db, I’ll update the answer

Comment: Yes,Validity is not a table.

Comment: I think I've missed the point of `ValueObject`, just checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects#important-characteristics-of-value-objects) and realized the you need a different solution!

Comment: I have already follow that docs,it is working.But in case of startDate and endDate,it is not working.

Comment: as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects#important-characteristics-of-value-objects) ValueObjects are immutable, I'm not sure if it means they are not updatable as well!

Comment: well, I didn't work with ValueObject but if it is not updatable, the only solution I can see is to kill the object and create a new one with new values

Comment: OK,I have got the solution